# Multiple functions with a single button in Java - Android

Tags: java, android

I have a button called **Option**,  which toggles the visibility of the `RadioGroup`. By default, **RadioBtn1** is selected and the text **"First Choice"** appears on `TextView`.

In this condition, if the **Option** button is clicked, I want to change its text to **"Close"**.  And, I want to change its text to **"Set"** if **RadioBtn2** is selected. Now, if we click the **Set** button, I want to makes the text **"Second Choice"** visible on `TextView`.

After that the **Set** button itself changes to previous **Option** button making the `RadioGroup` invisible again.

Here is the code I have tried:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@+id/textView" 
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
<Button 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:id="@+id/btn1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button1" />   
<Button 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:id="@+id/btn2" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button2" /> 
</LinearLayout>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
 <RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/radioBtn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="RadioBtn1" />
 <RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/radioBtn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioBtn2" />
</RadioGroup>
<Button 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:id="@+id/btnOption" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text= "Option" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
package com.infinitenotions.sample;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.lang.String;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import java.lang.Override;

public class HWSampleActivity extends Activity
{

private TextView textView;
private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btnOption;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioBtn1;
private RadioButton radioBtn2;

String text1 = "First Choice"; 
String text2 = "Second Choice";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btnOption = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOption);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioBtn1 = (RadioButton)findViewById (R.id.radioBtn1);
    radioBtn2 = (RadioButton)findViewById (R.id.radioBtn2);
   
    textView.setText(text1);
    
    btnOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
     btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     
     // **if text1 is visible which means radioBtn1 is checked 
        
        // set text of option button to "Close" 
        // on click "Close" button, change text to "Option" and return to previous state
        
        // if radioBtn2 is checked, change text of option button from "Close" to "Set" 
        // on click "Set" button, make text2 & btn2 visible, hide text1 & btn1, and change text from "Set" to "Option" as before
      
     // **and vice-versa, if text2 is visible

    }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Make your question more focus and clarity.

Comment: Link to the apk: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QL8JxplUD9wTwiNZv6EfFyY5rG_eFMIo/view  which may help you figure out my issue. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my question as well. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ocean make a onCLickListener for all buttons and update textView accordingly

Comment: I want to change text for textView, but before that want to change text of button to "Set". So that the button acts as setting.

Comment: Please do follow the **comments** given with the ```code``` for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I have resolved the issue, and it's working as expected.

I used a counter to toggle the visibility of the `RadioGroup`. And, I changed the state of the **Option** button with respect to the text visible on `TextView` and the checked state of the radio buttons.

```
package com.infinitenotions.sample;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.lang.String;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import java.lang.Override;

public class HWSampleActivity extends Activity
{
private TextView textView;
private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btnOption;
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioBtn1;
private RadioButton radioBtn2;    
private String text1 = "First Choice";
private String text2 = "Second Choice";
private String textClose = "Close";
private String textSet = "Set";
private String textOption = "Option";
private int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btnOption = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOption);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioBtn1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioBtn1);
    radioBtn2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioBtn2);
    
    textView.setText(text1);             
 
 btnOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        btnOption.setText((textClose));
        radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
        if(!textView.getText().equals(text2)) {
            radioBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                btnOption.setText((textSet));       
            }        
            });
        } 
        else if(textView.getText().equals(text2)) {
            radioBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                btnOption.setText((textSet));       
            }        
            });
        }               
        if (textView.getText().equals(text1) && radioBtn1.isChecked()) {
            radioBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                btnOption.setText((textClose));         
            }        
            });
        }
        else if (textView.getText().equals(text2) && radioBtn2.isChecked()) {
            radioBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                btnOption.setText((textClose));         
            }        
            });
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                           
    else {                                          
            radioGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnOption.setText((textOption));                
            if (radioBtn2.isChecked()) {
                btnOption.setText((textOption));
                textView.setText(text2);
                btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (radioBtn1.isChecked()) {
                btnOption.setText((textOption));
                textView.setText(text1);
                btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }                                                       
     }  
     counter++;                                                                  
     }});
}
}
```

Link to the working APK file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R4m3UwX2psUjpN6DvFogG0eZnIm-R64q/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid giving multiple functionalities to a single button will not work properly but I wrote this code with if statements that in each statement there is a `setOnClickListener()` method. Try this:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HWSampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
     TextView textView;
     Button btn1;
     Button btn2;
     Button btnOption;
     RadioGroup radioGroup;
     RadioButton radioBtn1;
     RadioButton radioBtn2;

    String text1 = "First Choice";
    String text2 = "Second Choice";
    String textClose = "Close";
    String textSet = "Set";
    String textOption = "Option";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btnOption = findViewById(R.id.btnOption);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioBtn1 = findViewById (R.id.radioBtn1);
        radioBtn2 = findViewById (R.id.radioBtn2);

        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setText(text1);

        if (btnOption.getText().equals(textOption)){
            btnOption.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (radioBtn1.isChecked())
                    btnOption.setText(textClose);
                else
                    btnOption.setText(textSet);
            });
        }

        if (btnOption.getText().equals(textClose)){
            btnOption.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                radioGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnOption.setText(textOption);
            });
        }

        if (btnOption.getText().equals(textSet)){
            btnOption.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textView.setText(text2);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

if this does not work, then you can use your **Button1** and **Button2** in order to change your text with these 2 buttons.

Comment: The buttons you mentioned are for different actions. These buttons can't be used to change text.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onCLickListener should work, Try this code

```
radioBtn1.setChecked(true);

btnOption.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
    if (radioGroup.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        radioGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnOption.setText("Close");
    }

    if (radioBtn2.isChecked()) {
        textView.setText("Second Choice");
    } else if (radioBtn1.isChecked()) {
        textView.setText("First Choice");
    }
});
        
radioBtn1.setOnClickListener(view13 -> btnOption.setText("Set"));
radioBtn2.setOnClickListener(view12 -> btnOption.setText("Set"));
```